# joining views with previous left joins and not multiplying rows

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, view

I have 2 views of the form:

```
--View1
SELECT foo.id AS id FROM foo LEFT JOIN bar ON foo.id = bar.id
--Results
id
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 ...


--View2
SELECT foo.id AS id FROM foo LEFT JOIN manchu ON foo.id = manchu.id
--Results
id
 1
 1
 1
 2
 2
 ...
```

Now I want to join the two views so that row #1 from View1 is joined to row #1 of View2.

If I join on View1.id = View2.id, then the rows will multiply by each other, which isn't what I want.
Is there a way I can add a column to each view with a unique number that I can join on? Or another solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If not multiple rows, which is what most people would want, what exactly is it that you want? Which rows of View2 should be joined to? If you can answer this, you you're halfway there answering your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following as a column in each view:

```
ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as sequence
```

Your view join would then be `View1.sequence = View2.sequence`

But, your intent is still unclear.  It appears you want to join row 1 in each view, and join row 2 in each view, etc.  With what you've shown us, you're queries don't guarantee the row sequence for duplicate id values.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. With my real life example I do have some underlying code that guarantees row order. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT id` in both views instead of `SELECT id` and join them on `View1.id = View2.id`. In this case you will have
id
1
2
etc.
If you need different results, plz specify in your question what exactly you want to get.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work as it will only return one of the ids. I need all of them.